# Socket.io server emits not firing

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Ok trying my hand at NodeJS and socket.io and have run into a problem.  I have NodeJS and Socket.io installed and running on my localhost.  At present I have the following setup:

**server.js**

```
// Require HTTP module (to start server) and Socket.IO
var http = require('http'), io = require('socket.io');

// Start the server at port 8080
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 

// Send HTML headers and message
  res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
  res.end('<h1>NodeJS Server Online</h1>');
});
server.listen(8080);

// Create a Socket.IO instance, passing it our server
var socketserver = io.listen(server);

// Add a connect listener
socketserver.on('connection', function(socket){ 

    socket.emit("server ready");

    socket.on('test', function (msg) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('TEST:', msg);
        console.log(msg);
    });

    socket.on('user message', function (msg) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('user message', msg);
        console.log(msg);
    });

});
```

**client.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready;
    var socket =  io.connect('http://localhost',{port:8080});

    socket.on('server ready',function() {
        messages.append("<li>Server Ready...</li>");
        console.log("Server Ready");
    });

    // Add a connect listener
    socket.on('connect',function() {
        messages.append("<li>Connected...</li>");
        console.log("connected");
        socket.emit('test',"Just testing");
    });

});
```

Server starts fine, but my problem is that the server.js does not fire the **socket.emit("server ready");** line.  The client side code works fine as in terminal.app on testing my server outputs this line:

```
websocket received data packet 5:::{"name":"test","args":["Just testing"]}
```

What am I missing? Why isn't the server side stuff firing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated socket.io to 0.7.2 and then slightly modified your example to use express. The code below was able to receive the "server ready" event.

Node Server:

```
var http = require('http'),  
    express = require('express');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.listen(9000);
console.log("server started");

// socket.io 
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){ 
    socket.emit('server ready', {msg: 'hi'}) ;
});
```

Web Page (/sock.html):

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script> 
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('server ready', function(data){ console.log('server ready!'); }) ;
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why express? For many projects I have only needed to serve 1 html file and express is just too much for that case imo

Comment: Maybe because all socket.io tutorials out there use express in their example?